# How to use a django framework with phonegap?

Tags: django, cordova

I have been looking online and there are some articles about people using Django web framework  and Phonegap to build mobile applications.

However, it says on phonegap to upload your HTML, JS, and CSS files to the build. Does that mean you cannot use django to build mobile apps with phonegap?

Any clarifications or steps on how to build would be great.

Comment: Use Django for the backend and Phonegap for the Mobile application. You can't run Django on the mobile device directly.

Comment: Okay. So what would i upload to phonegap? My templates?

Comment: You don't use django templates here. You separate the phonegap application and django application. You only expose djangos views for your phonegap application to call.

Answer (score 1):

Think of PhoneGap as preloaded static web pages in a WebKit view.  You can add JavaScript (most people use JQuery/JQueryMobile) to make it dynamic and use AJAX calls to load data from a server but rendering templates is not what it does.  You can do fragments but it's not the same thing as Django Templates.

I am working on a project that handles data loading via an API from a server running Django.  The App is being written in PhoneGap and uses AJAX calls for getting the extra data.  I'd say look at django apps like TastyPie for helping get data.  The main goals in using PhoneGap are 1) better load times of HTML since it's local, 2) Reduced traffic by only sending API data and thus better for cellular networks and 3) access to native feaures in the hardware you don't otherwise get access to with JS in a webpage.